# How does the bootstrap grid works. need a clarification of its usage across devices

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using a bootstrap front end framework. Can I use the bootstrap system for multiple devices?

Comment: Read the documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/

Comment: Please [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and refer to the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com)

Comment: Yes, bootstraps is designed in a 12 column fashion meaning you use classes to determine how many columns it will take up on on what size device. For example 2 col-xs-6 divs will take up the full width of the screen each 50% width on an "extra small" device where as one col-xs-12 will take up the full screen you can also use use the classes inside a parent to take up a certain amount of space inside of the parent

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can use for multiple devices.

Do you face any issue in usage?

Comment: Thanks Bright. Yes, I am having difficulty for multiple devices. By the way do you know Which bootstrap styles are used to create a vertical pills navigation?

Comment: Go with .nav, .nav-tabs, .nav-stacked